# How to execute a sql script from a url?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 10 sql scripts lying on 10 SVN urls.

I want to write a single sql script which execute those 10 svn sql scripts.

for example, `http://svn/s1.sql`, `http://svn/s1.sq2`, ....

I want to write a single sql which does like `execute http://svn/s1.sql`, `execute http://svn/s2.sql`, etc

How can I do it?

Comment: You would need to write a program that downloads the files, reads them in line by line, appends them internally and executes the whole batch

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno I can't do this in sql directly?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Also that would be a huge security hole, if you could execute SQL scripts by calling a url in your browser.

Comment: Executing code directly from SVN of any other source control system is usually a bad idea, because in the URL above you will always get the latest version of the file, which may not be the one you want to run. It's usually better to get the files from source control based on a version number, label or whatever, then run them. That means you can deploy version X to server Y much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can run all the .SQL files using [**sqlcmd**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms170572.aspx)

First Create a Batch file and Paste the below coding in that batch file :

```
sqlcmd -S ServerName -U Username -P password -i c:\s1.sql -o C:\s1.txt
sqlcmd -S ServerName -U Username -P password -i c:\s2.sql -o C:\s2.txt
sqlcmd -S ServerName -U Username -P password -i c:\s3.sql -o C:\s3.txt
sqlcmd -S ServerName -U Username -P password -i c:\s4.sql -o C:\s4.txt
```

Execute the Batch file from SQL Server like below..

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'c:filename.bat'
```

You can also refer the Below link for running batch file..

[**SQL SERVER – Running Batch File Using T-SQL – xp_cmdshell bat file**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/27/sql-server-running-batch-file-using-t-sql-xp_cmdshell-bat-file/)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a program that downloads the files, reads them in line by line, appends them internally and executes the whole batch.

It would be a huge security hole, if you could execute SQL scripts by calling a url in your browser.